# Webscraping Table with Python

Tags: python

So at the moment I am trying to webscrape the following race table from the following:
https://cris.rwwa.com.au/racefield.aspx?meeting=5159089&race=1

My code at the moment:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://cris.rwwa.com.au/racefield.aspx?meeting=5159089&race=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
raceTable = soup.find('table', class_ = 'tblcris raceField')

for racer in raceTable.find_all('table')[1]:
    rows = racer.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        try:
            rowdata = row.findAll('td')
            horseNumber.append(rowdata[1].text)
            horseName.append(rowdata[2].text)
            riderName.append(rowdata[8].text)
            trainerName.append(rowdata[9].text)
            print(horseNumber, horseName, riderName, trainerName)
        except:
            print("field is Null")
```

when ran I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Adv Python\wk2\webScraping.py", line 11, in <module>
    for racer in raceTable.find_all('table')[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

From this I am not entirely sure what is going wrong as I am fairly new to webscraping, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://cris.rwwa.com.au/racefield.aspx?meeting=5159089&race=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all("table")

table = tables[1]

rows = table.find_all("tr")
# skip first two rows, they don't contain any data
rows = rows[2:]
for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_all("td")
    try:
        print("horse number ", tds[1].text)
        print("horse name ", tds[2].text)
        print("rider name ", tds[8].text)
        print("trainer name ", tds[9].text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```